# NSOutlineView and subviews lose proportion when app Window loses focus

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3

My app implements `NSOutlineView` on the left side. Everything looks good until the app loses focus; then, suddenly the outline view becomes discombobulated (all its subviews lose proportion).

When focus returns to the app, the outline view reverts to the proper proportions. Not sure what is happening. Any ideas? (See image of broken behavior below).

The app is developed with XCode 8 in Swift 3, and my `NSOutlineView` has a implements a datasource and a delegate.

[image]

Comment: You should probably include some code in your post.